# Is there the opposite of click event in Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I made a search bar with search icon. I want this, when I click the #forminput, #search will return white; and after I click another object, #search will return lightgray color. How can I do this?
My codes:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#forminput").click(function(){
$("#search").css("color", "white");
});
});
```

Have a nice day.

Comment: You might be able to use CSS based on the focus state of the input. Please include your HTML so that we can see a working demonstration of the code you've got. Thanks!

Comment: opposite of click, aka [focus] is [blur].

Comment: @Barmar, I don't think it is a dupe, but anyways. `:)`

Comment: @PraveenKumar Maybe I misunderstood, but he says he wants to do something when you click an object other than the search icon.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use `off` and give the event handler:

```
$("#forminput").off("click");
```

But if you want to restore to an earlier state, it is always wise to use just CSS for presentation and then use JavaScript to toggle between the classes. Considering your current situation, I believe just CSS is enough.

```css
input {color: #999; padding: 10px; width: 200px;}
input:focus {color: #000;}
```

```html
<input type="text" value="Default Gray, Click Black." />
```

Comment: Thanks, I solved this problem. I used focus and blur events.

Comment: @UbeydeEmirÖzdemir Okay nice to hear.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go with the solution https://jsfiddle.net/8gygvdwy/

```js
$('input[type=text]').focus(function(){
 $(this).css({
   'background': '#ccc'
  });
}).focusout(function(){
 $(this).css({
   'background': '#fff'
  });
});

$('input[type=button]').click( function(){
 $('input[type=text]').css({
   'background': '#fff'
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="search" />
<input type="button" value="Submit" />
```

Comment: Thanks, I solved this problem. I used focus and blur events.

Comment: @UbeydeEmirÖzdemir Awesome to hear that :) Please share your code as answer and so that I any one faces the same issue will be able to find the solution.